# JQuery Speed too slow on IE

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I am using JQuery to show/hide divs as the user types in a field. It works but VERY slowly on IE8 and under. I've tried various combinations of hiding all divs then only showing appropriate ones, showing all divs and only hiding appropriate ones, etc. I am assuming the issue has to do with the fact I return almost 30,000 rows of data (EDIT: I should have said 4,000 rows of data 30,000 lines of html). BUT since it works so smoothly in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc I thought maybe, MAYBE there would be something I could do to improve the speed in IE. I know, for instance I had to change the way I user trim, and there are a couple of ways to use :not. So maybe there is something else I can do? I kept commented code in so that you can see other options I've tried, but maybe didn't get the right combination down.

```
function updateRecords(e){
  //references are all uppercase
  var searchVal = $.trim($("#searchReference").val().toUpperCase());
  var refCount = $('[id^="'+searchVal+'"]').attr('count');
  if ((e.keyCode == 8) || (searchVal == '')){//this checks for backspace
    $('.refRows').css({"display":"block"}); 
  }
  if (searchVal != '')
  {
  //$('.refRows').hide();
  //$('.refRows').css("display","none");
  $(".refRows").not('[id^="'+searchVal+'"]').css({"display":"none"});
  //$(".refRows:not(" + searchVal + ")").css({"display":"none"});
  //$('.refRows[id^="'+searchVal+'"]').css("display","inline-block");
  }
}
```

Comment: 30,000 rows? Why so many at once?

Comment: you could set up a time interval and wait for the user to finish typing before hiding and showing the divs, otherwise I'm guessing they will stack up and process slower. Also 30.000 REALLY a lot, that could lead to memory problems for some users, you should consider splitting it in different pages.

Comment: try setting up a class (I usually name none) that has display set to none and then applying that class rather than directly accessing the css property of each element. It will still have the same refresh but might make it slightly smoother. (you can then use $('.none').removeClass('none'); to show all rows)

Comment: @scrappedcola- i will try your idea as well. thanks.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/fn-not-vs-selector-not

Comment: I ended up having to use an iframe. reloading a page is a lot faster than jquery in this instance.